# Differentiating - folder that is being copied into and a normal folder

Tags: c#, powershell

Is there a mechanism by which I can scan for a new folder in a particular location - and determine if the new folder is fully created or if files are still being copied into it.

Essentially, is there a folder property that indicates if its contents have been fully copied into it or the copying is currently going on?

One mechanism I thought was to monitor the folder size in fixed time intervals and if it changes it means that the copying is going on - however this method might not be foolproof.

EDIT: To be more specific, I just want to know if there is a flag or lock that is set to a folder that indicates if its contents are being copied into it at that instant.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that two processes are going to write into the same folder at the same time?  Why don't you just reject any attempts at copying to a folder that was not created by the copying process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915297/check-if-folder-is-in-use-in-c-sharp

Comment: That would work if I had to copy to the newly created folder - but in my case I want the contents of that new folder. And I do want its contents fully after all the copying is done into it.

Comment: First you need to define what you mean by "fully copied". What if there is a program that copies a new file into the folder once every 15 seconds. (E.g., it's saving pictures from a security camera.) What would it mean for this folder to be "fully copied"?

Comment: I am talking about a normal scenario where the copying is continuous and not intermittent at intervals. If I am not clear, think of a set of 100 10 MB files that are being copied into a new folder after a simple select all->copy->paste to new location.

Comment: This is a semantic concept, not a file system concept. You will have to decide what your definition is, and then go implement it.

Comment: @RaymondChen: You are absolutely correct in that my question was ambiguous about "fully copied", let me try to clarify that. I assume that if a copy operation is not currently in place for the folder it is fully copied. Essentially my question boils down to - is there a copy process that is currently going on for the folder - if YES then its not fully copied - if NO it is fully copied. Appreciate your help.

Comment: There is no such ting as "a copy operation" in the file system. You need to break down your definition further. You are thinking too high level.